# Multiple stock using quantmod in shiny

Tags: r, shiny, quantmod, performanceanalytics

I have written a code for calculating correlation of stocks in R and this is the code.

```
library(quantmod)
tickers<-c('AAPL','GOOG','MSFT')
stockData=new.env()
getSymbols(tickers,src = "yahoo", env=stockData,from =as.Date("2016-01-01"))
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

  x <- list()
  Data=data.frame()
  clo=data.frame()
  for (i in 1:length(tickers)) {
    x[[i]] <- get(tickers[i], pos=stockData)  # get data from stockData environment  
    clo<-cbind(clo,Cl(x[[i]]))
    Data=cbind(Data,diff(log(Cl(x[[i]]))))
  }
chart.Correlation(Data)
Cl(Data)
tail(clo)
```

But I am getting a hard time converting this into a shiny app

This is so far i have done in my shiny app. I have selected `shinysky` library for selecting multiple stocks

ui.R

```
#ui.R

library(shinysky)
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("test"),

  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("text"),

      select2Input("txt","stock",choices=c("AAPL","GOOG","MSFT"),selected=c("")),

      actionButton("go","submit") 


     ),

    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type="tab",tabPanel("Plot",plotOutput("plot")),tabPanel("summary",tableOutput("table")),tabPanel("close",tableOutput("table1")))

    )
  )
))
```

server.R

```
# server.R
library(quantmod)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

stockData <- new.env()
  dataInput <- reactive({ 
    if(input$go==0){return()} #confirming button click
    else if(input$go==1){
      validate(
        need(input$txt != "", label = "stock")
      )
       getSymbols(input$txt, src = "yahoo", env=stockData,from =as.Date(input$dates) )          


    }
      })

output$plot=plot chart.correlation
output$table=table of Close values of stocks etc Cl(Data)
output$table1=output of last close
}
)
```

The above shiny code is incomplete because I have no idea how to go further and have some logic error.

1) I have used `if(input$go==0){return()}` to validate button click but it only work once

2) while deploying this code in shinyapps.io `library(PerformanceAnalytics)` interfere and doesn't allow deployment

How can I solve these problems?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before diving into `shiny` please look into the tutorials on their page, they will cover a lot of material much needed to further develop your apps.

**For #1**

```
rm(list = ls())
library(shiny)
library(xts)
library(DT)
library(quantmod)
library(shinysky)
library(PerformanceAnalytics)
x <- list()
Data <- data.frame()
clo <- data.frame()

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("test"),
  tags$style(type="text/css",".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"),
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      helpText("text"),
      select2Input("txt","stock",choices=c("AAPL","GOOG","MSFT"),selected=c("AAPL","GOOG")),
      dateInput("dates", "Date:", value = "2016-01-01"),
      actionButton("go","submit") 
    ),
    mainPanel(
      tabsetPanel(type="tab",tabPanel("Plot",plotOutput("plot")),tabPanel("summary",dataTableOutput("table")),tabPanel("close",dataTableOutput("table1")))  
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  stockData <- new.env()
  dataInput <- reactive({ 
    if(input$go==0){return()} #confirming button click
    isolate({
      input$go
      getSymbols(input$txt, src = "yahoo", env=stockData,from =as.Date(input$dates) )    
      Data <- data.frame()

      validate(need(input$txt != "", label = "stock"))
      for (i in 1:length(input$txt)) {
        x[[i]] <- get(input$txt[i], pos=stockData)  # get data from stockData environment  
        Data <- cbind(Data,diff(log(Cl(x[[i]]))))
      }
      Data
    })
  })

  Last_Close <- reactive({
    if(input$go==0){return()} #confirming button click
    isolate({
      input$go
      validate(need(input$txt != "", label = "stock"))
      for (i in 1:length(input$txt)) {
        x[[i]] <- get(input$txt[i], pos=stockData)  # get data from stockData environment  
        clo <- cbind(clo,Cl(x[[i]]))
      }
      clo
    })
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot(chart.Correlation(dataInput()))
  output$table <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(as.data.frame(Cl(dataInput()))))
  output$table1 <- DT::renderDataTable(datatable(as.data.frame(Cl(Last_Close()))))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

Comment: When I run your codes to test your app, there has this [error](http://i.imgur.com/UoSpiGX.png?1), and the error keeping there after I modified a bit `validate(need(input$txt != "" & !is.null(input$txt) & is.vector(input$txt), label = "stock"))`

Comment: you must be on a different version of R and shiny that I was when this was answered

Comment: I've changed the `reactivePlot()` to `renderPlot`. Here is my system info :

`> ## devtools::session_info()$platform : 
 setting  value,
 version  R version 3.2.3 (2015-12-10),
 system   x86_64, linux-gnu,
 ui       RStudio (0.99.896),
 language (EN),
 collate  en_US.UTF-8,
 tz       America/New_York,
 date     2016-05-03 `